# How to share hash reference in multithread perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-safety

How do I share the hash reference `$ref` across main thread and worker threads ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $ref = {};
$ref->{0}->{abc} = 123;
$ref->{1}->{abc} = 223;

printf( "%d\n", $ref->{0}->{abc} );
printf( "%d\n", $ref->{1}->{abc} );

issue_all_jobs($ref);

while (1)
{
    printf( "%d\n", $ref->{0}->{abc} );
    printf( "%d\n", $ref->{1}->{abc} );
    sleep(1);
}

sub issue_all_jobs
{
    my ($ref) = @_;
    for ( my $i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ )
    {
        $ref->{$i}->{handle} = new threads( \&issue_job, $ref, $i );
        $ref->{$i}->{handle}->detach();
    }
}

sub issue_job
{
    my ( $ref, $i ) = @_;
    $ref->{$i}->{abc} = 555123 + $i;
    sleep(2);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work as well as you might think. One of the limitations of `threads::shared` is that it works fine for sharing single dimensional containers, but it gets rather messy when trying to work on nested data structures, because the compiler doesn't 'know' what it needs to share.

http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html#BUGS-AND-LIMITATIONS

So - for starters - you need to designate your shared variables as shared in the first place. Either at declaration:

```
my $ref : shared;
```

But as you're trying to share a hash

```
shared_clone ( $ref );
```

But personally - I'd shy away from such things. I dislike using shared memory objects, and would generally prefer to use [`Thread::Semaphore`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Semaphore.html) and [`Thread::Queue`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Queue.html) and pass data back and forth in a queue. [`Storable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) helps a great deal with this, as you can `freeze` and `thaw` a data object for insertion into a queue.

Comment: Thank you for continuing to bring your threading expertise to SO.  I appreciate your contributions.

Comment: Major reason I started learning threading/forking - and for that matter, OO - is because it makes all the people I know who are on a high horse about how 'perl is inferior' look a bit sick when I suggest it.